# Use azure media service / server with xamarin

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

Have anyone used azure media service with xamarin. I am trying to make an portable library which can upload / retrieves video asseset from a standard azure media server. However I am not able to install the nuget package into my project.

Can anyone point me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the default azure media libary is a portable library therefore you cannot add it to your portable library project.

You could however implement this using the available rest documentation.

[Media Services Rest Api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973617.aspx)

We've done something similar for access to blob storage. To avoid having to reference all the azure storage libraries in all our projects.